# How to disable back button on report?

Tags: jasperserver

I am accessing report using URL like in example:

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&standAlone=true&_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=%2Freports%2Finteractive&reportUnit=%2Freports%2Finteractive%2FCustomersReport
```

I have also added custom theme to hide JasperServer decorators by folowing link: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/embedding-ad-hoc-http-api

The only problem I am facing is when user click on **Back** button, they are exiting the report and they can see list of reports in repository. I would like to disable that behavior so that Back button just does nothing in that case. I have tried to customize the behavior as described in: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/setting-default-flow-action-back-button but I can't find the proper value to replace the default action:

```
<end-state id="done" view="flowRedirect:searchFlow?lastMode=true" />
```

I have tried replacing it with

```
    <end-state id="done" view="json:none" />
```

but that gave me some crazy error.

Hiding button by CSS is not a option since I need the back button to work when user is viewing sub-reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this issue for Input Control form button.

Under **"...\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\jsp\modules\viewReport"** directory, in **ViewReport.jsp** file, I searched for "**ICDialog**" text and deleted related statements with ICDialog. Then I restarted the jasperserver by "**servicerun.bat**" and "**servicerun.bat START**" commands.

I think, this will work for back button and the others.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up the roles/users so the logged in user can only view reports allowed by that user. This would be a better solution than trying to circumvent the browser functionality. Alternatively if you have an application you are trying to embed jasper in you could use the web services to just download the report required by the user and not enable them to access the server webpage.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are two problems.. first, I need sub-reports so exporting is not an option because I need drill-down functionality.. Second, I don't want users to be able to set parameters for report on their own, since I need control over that too (from external application).

Comment: If you have drill-down, you can always add a button to drill back up as a report execution hyperlink passing the original parameters back to the first report if required

Comment: Thx for the idea.. for now I have redirected that final flow to not-authorized page so I will see how will that work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `&decorate=no` at the end of the URL.
Now the url like this `{url_for_jasper_report}&decorate=no`

Adding this query parameter you can hide the back button as well as the footer and header